# WCF binding query TCP VS HTTP

Tags: wcf

When do you actually use TCP as a binding element and when do you use HTTP?
I want to know scenarios and performance issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCP is must faster as compared to http. Even tcp is more secure and reliable.

Please refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733769.aspx for more detailed information.

Actually choosing binding depends on many factors and reading above article will give you insight in more dept.

Answer (score 3):

TCP will send less "valueless" data than Http. Http will add a lot of data when serializing it.

You may use TCP in a local network or a vpn.

Here you can see a chart of how to choose between these bindings:
http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/dennis/archive/2006/12/01/WCF-Binding-decision-chart.aspx