# advantage of using TCP protocol over HTTP

Tags: wcf, tcp

I have read WCF supports TCP protocol also. However why would I want to use TCP instead of HTTP? What are the advantages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WCF binding query TCP VS HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931686/wcf-binding-query-tcp-vs-http)

Answer (score 0):

You should really read the Bindings section in Chapter 1 of Juval Lowy's book "[Programming WCF Services](https://ashishmit99.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/oreilly-programming-wcf-services-3rd-edition-aug-2010.pdf)".  I could only find a 3rd edition online, but it is currently in its 4th edition.